# On a pfsense router how would I redirect one IP to another?

Tags: pfsense, amazon-rds

I have a poorly made piece of software at work that only asks for a IP when connecting and cant use URL and I cant get a static IP for the database its connecting to (Amazon RDS).

I was wondering if there was a way that I am not aware of to use a IP like a URL where i could redirect something like 9.9.9.9 to always point to whatever the current IP of the database is?

I am using pfsense and have tried outbound nat rules but that is not working unless mos likely I am not entering it correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with Nat. But you should be able to do it with the load balancer service.
Set your external AWS ip as a pool, then create a virtual server to redirect to that pool.

Here is some docs on that
[Pfsense Load Balance and Virutal Servers](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Inbound_Load_Balancing)